# Python Redis: DUMP payload version or checksum are wrong

Tags: python, redis

I'm trying to copy all keys from one redis database to my local machine.  After setting up both connections and calling `flushdb` on the local copy to clear all of the keys, I run this:

```
for key in src.keys('*'):
    ttl = src.ttl(key)
    # Handle TTL command returning -1 (no expire) or -2 (no key)
    if ttl < 0:
        ttl = 0
    dst.restore(key, ttl, src.dump(key))
```

Some of the keys are getting correctly restored, but then at some point I run into `redis.exceptions.ResponseError: DUMP payload version or checksum are wrong`

Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: That's curious - what versions are your source and destination Redis?

Comment: So I believe the problem was related to TTLs.  If I removed or otherwise omitted all keys with TTLs, the script runs fine.  I'm not sure if that dst.restore checks the given TTL against whatever src.dump outputs or something?

Answer (score 0):

Can you recreate the offending payload?